# how can I override console.log() and prepend a word at the beginning of the output?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the function Log which prints data along with passed arguments, how can I print the content & at the same time always print the word "Report: " at the beginning of the log.

```
function Log(){
    if (app.debug_logs){
        if(console && console.log){
            console.log.apply(console, "Report: " + arguments);
        }
    }
}

Log(" error occurred ", " on this log... ");
```

I want to have:
"Report: error occurred on this log..."

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can override the `console.log` easily

```
(function(){
    if(window.console && console.log){
        var old = console.log;
        console.log = function(){
            Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, 'Report: ');
            old.apply(this, arguments)
        }
    }  
})();

console.log('test')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7QsJ4/1/)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté because it is SO and you can do what ever you want to do

Comment: well I'm aware of SO's anonymous voting system, though anonymous downvoting a perfectly valid answer is just not constructive at all.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté might be because I deviated from the original question, the question was about the `Log` method instead of fixing it I suggested overriding `console.log`. Don't know still whether it is offroad

Comment: True that, though the title clearly states `override console.log` so this should be valid as well.

Comment: How about the simpler `console.log = function () { old.apply(this, ['Report: '].concat(arguments)) }` ?

Comment: this is loosing the original line, so all of the logs would appear from the same line

Comment: @DotNetWise sorry.. can you explain the case further... probably edit the fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: Did you try in jsfiddle yourself?

It always reports the console log line to be the line of old.apply so it makes console.log pretty much useless
http://jsfiddle.net/gf937pd1/

Comment: @DotNetWise I think that was the requirement... where OP wanted to debug/trace some special condition and this was a temporary arrangement

Comment: @DotNetWise: Are you so self absorbed that you think *your* requirements must be *everyone's* requirements? Maybe the person asking doesn't care about that. Maybe they know there are other methods they could use to get the line info. Didn't really think it through, did ya.

Comment: well, rather than not append that text, than loosing the location who called the console.log
Beacuse then, debugging is rather useless or impossible