# embed _generated_background_page to options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background, console.log

I made Chrome extension which working fine, but need to be modified this way:
console.log of background.js should be monitored in real time by user constantly, while options page opened, as an element of this page. At the worst case, it may be duplicate of log, but generated in background.js.

How can I access and display this data, where background script process external data once a second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed the background page in another page.

To do what you are looking to do, you can [override `console.log` to do extra stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259711/how-can-i-override-console-log-and-append-a-word-at-the-beginning-of-the-outpu):

```
// background.js
(function() {
  if(window.console && console.log) {
    var old = console.log;
    console.log = function() {
      // Do extra stuff here
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: "backgroundLogEvent",
        content: arguments
      });

      // Call normal console.log
      old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }  
})();
```

And in the options page, you can receive those messages:

```
// options.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.type == "backgroundLogEvent") {
    // Do something with message.arguments
    // I.e. log them here:
    message.arguments.unshift('From background:');
    console.log.apply(console, message.arguments);
  }
});
```

This will transmit all `console.log` messages from background in realtime.

Exercise for the reader: implement a buffer that shows a short history before opening the options page.