# How to show javascript console for an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe on my page:

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

And there's a div on my page where I'd like to show the javascript console for it:

```
<div id='console'></div>
```

So in the iframe, if a script did:
`console.log("hello world");`

it would show in my console div.

Is there a way to do this? Also, I don't want to open developer tools. I want the console to be shown as part of my page within the html.

Comment: Is iframe on the same domain?

Comment: Why do you want to use default `console` functionality? Can't you write own console instead?

Comment: As for the second part of your question - displaying the output of `console.log` on the page, perhaps this might be useful: [how can I override console.log()...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259711/how-can-i-override-console-log-and-append-a-word-at-the-beginning-of-the-outpu)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961229/is-there-a-way-to-change-context-to-iframe-in-javascript-console

Comment: I want a cross browser solution. So that didn't answer my question.

Comment: you can use `cd` in dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the console value in your HTML entity.

```
<iframe id="xyz"></iframe>

var iframeWindow = document.getElementById("xyz").contentWindow;

iframeWindow.console.log = function(val) {
    var divId = document.getElementById("console");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
    divId.appendChild(span);
};
```

this will get all the console.log of the iframe and append to the div

Comment: This doesn't work. You can override the `iframeWindow.console.log` function, but doing so doesn't change anything.