# Differentiate console.log from two iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page (let's call it main page) with two IFrames showing the same page (let's call it child page).

If I write a `console.log('hello')` in the javascript code of my child page, when I load my main page I get in my console two equal messages `hello`.

Is there a way to differentiate from which IFrame the log comes? Or, put in another way, how can I understand from which of the two IFrames the log is coming?

Comment: In Chrome, above your console, you can see a dropdown with "<top frame>" selected. Just select the iframe in that list, and you'll only get the logs from that one. Same goes for IE (Target dropdown). For Firefox, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes).

Comment: @blex I tried in Chrome, but it doesn't seem to work. Whatever frame I select I see all the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could differenciate them by adding a hash in the url, e.g.:

```
<iframe src="child.html#iframe-1"></iframe>
<iframe src="child.html#iframe-2"></iframe>
```

Then, in your child page, override the `console.log` function so that it adds that hash as a prefix:

```
if(window.console && console.log){
    var old = console.log;
    console.log = function(){
        Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, window.location.hash + ': ');
        old.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
console.log('hi'); // Will output '#iframe-X: hi'
```

*The code to override the console is from [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259739/1913729).*

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the location in your console statement like this:

```
console.log(window.location.pathname, 'hello');
```

Comment: sadly the pathname is equal between the two Iframes