# overwrite console.log with chrome extension (content script)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a tiny chrome-extension, which redirects the console.log output to a http server via an ajax call. But I discovered, that I cannot overwrite the console.log function. The content script (for testing):

```
console.log = function() { return 0 }
```

it keeps the function untouched.

Anybody knows, what could be the reason? Is there maybe another way to archive this?

Comment: When you say you cannont overwrite the console.log function do you mean you are calling the fucntion console.log and you do not see it in the console? If so I can tell you why. Please tell me your file structure

Comment: hi! if I type in the code line from my post to the console, and afterwards I try to call the function console.log("bla"), I get the expected result: 0 - so console.log is overwritten by my specified function, which returns 0. But it doesn't behave equally when I put the code to a content script, the script runs, but if it do the same test in the console afterwards I get an unchanged console.log function returning "bla".  What do you mean by file structure in this context?

Comment: I you are writing a chrome extension and trying to check consol.log in the browser on the current tab you are viewing then this won't work. You can make a file like popup.js which will activate when you click its icon then check the console on the popup. But you have to write a lot more code to communicate with the extension in the background and the tab your viewing in the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

Content scripts run in [isolated contexts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). You can workaround this by creating a script tag and injecting it into the DOM.

```
var script = document.createElement("script")
script.textContent = "console.log = function() { return 0 }"
document.appendChild(script)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment or vote, so I just put comment here and please feel free to remove my answer.

I recommend you refer [how can I override console.log() and append a word at the beginning of the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259711/how-can-i-override-console-log-and-append-a-word-at-the-beginning-of-the-outpu) .

Comment: His problem is hes using an extension and trying to console.log. You cannot communicate with the open tab and the background extension by simply console.log